# Snakemake using the same input and output in a rule

Tags: snakemake

Is it possible to use the same input and output in a rule?

For example,

```
rule example:
    input:
        "/path/to/my/data"
    output:
        "/path/to/my/data"
    shell:
        "my_command {input}"
```

I am pulling data from a previous rule, and am trying to move some of its outputs around, and merge files together.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, no. Snakemake builds a DAG (directed acyclic graph) and then makes the dependencies for each node required by a target. In your case you are introducing a loop.

Anyway, from your description I don't see any reason for this cycle:

> I am pulling data from a previous rule, and am trying to move some of
> its outputs around, and merge files together.

That can be done in a "normal" way.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I'd like this rule's output to place data into the input folder, but I may be able to use a parameter for my actual output, and a dummy/temp folder in the `output:` portion

Comment: You may resolve this ambiguity by completely removing the file from the output section, but add ing a "flag file" into output. The absense of the flag would mean that you still need to update your file, the presence -- that the update is complete.